# Perl, Assign to variable from regex match

Tags: regex, perl, syntax, variable-assignment, parentheses

I am relatively new to perl and there is an example snippet of code in [check_ilo2_health.pl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/HP-%28Compaq%29/check_ilo2_health/details) in which there is a piece of syntax that I do not understand how or why it works. The code snippet is parsing SSL client data, in this case XML, line by line.

```
if ( $line =~ m/MESSAGE='/) {
   my ($msg) = ( $line =~ m/MESSAGE='(.*)'/);  #<---- HERE

   if ( $msg !~ m/No error/ ) {
      if ( $msg =~ m/Syntax error/ ) {  #...etc
```

An example of the XML in question:

```
<RESPONSE
    STATUS="0x0000"
    MESSAGE='No error'
 />
```

So in this case the *if* statement takes the *MESSAGE* line of the XML sample. I understand that *my ($msg)* treats the variable as a sort of list and I understand how the regular expressions match; however, what I do not understand is the syntax such that *$msg* is **assigned** to *No error*. The perl seems to be playing around with parenthesis syntax and such for this to work. While it works I would like to know how it works. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are referring to the `=~` or `!~`, those are [binding operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Perlretut, Extracting-matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches):

> ... in scalar context, `$time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/` returns a true or false value. In list context, however, it returns the list of matched values `($1,$2,$3)`

So, in

```
($msg) = ( $line =~ m/MESSAGE='(.*)'/);
```

`( $line =~ m/MESSAGE='(.*)'/)` returns a list of the matches by the capturing groups. You have one capturing group, so the content of that is then stored in ($msg).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This makes sense. I would upvote your answer since you provided a link to your source but I still have less than 15 reputation. Oh well. +1